# Run redis without interactive WSL shell

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, services, redis

I'm moving my development environment to a new laptop and cannot get redis installed the same way as the old machine.

To avoid [XY](https://xyproblem.info/), my goal is to have redis server run locally in WSL *and I not need an interactive WSL shell running* - this was happening on the old machine and what I'm having trouble accomplishing on the new machine.

The biggest difference is the old machine uses Ubuntu 20.04 and the new one pulled down Ubuntu 22.04 and I know a lot has changed.

### What I've tried

I usually follow [these instructions](https://anggo.ro/note/installing-redis-in-ubuntu-wsl/) - I've tried twice and they both end up the same: the new machine works and redis is available to connect to when the console is running, but after [about 8 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#the-8-second-rule) the client is dropped and cannot reconnect.

One thing I noticed is a difference between `ps -auxf` output, redis is parented by init on the old machine and does not have a parent tree on the new machine.

**Old Machine**

```
old-machine:~$ ps -auxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2328  1520 ?        Sl   09:34   0:00 /init
root         4  0.0  0.0   2324     4 ?        Sl   09:34   0:00 plan9 --control-socket 5 --log-level 4 --server-fd 6 --pipe-fd 8 --log-truncate
root         7  0.0  0.0   2336   112 ?        Ss   09:34   0:00 /init
root         8  0.0  0.0   2352   120 ?        S    09:34   0:00  \_ /init
me           9  0.0  0.0  10196  5204 pts/0    Ss   09:34   0:00      \_ -bash
me         118  0.0  0.0  10868  3228 pts/0    R+   09:49   0:00      |   \_ ps -auxf
redis       47  0.0  0.0  51712  9948 ?        Ssl  09:36   0:00      \_ /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

**New Machine**

```
new-machine:~$ ps -auxf
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0 165840 10944 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /sbin/init
root           2  0.0  0.0   2328   940 ?        Sl   09:13   0:00 /init
root           5  0.0  0.0   2352    80 ?        Sl   09:13   0:00  \_ plan9 --control-socket 6 --log-level 4 --server-fd 7 --pipe-fd 9 --log-truncate
root         327  0.0  0.0   2336   112 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00  \_ /init
root         329  0.0  0.0   2352   120 ?        S    09:13   0:00  |   \_ /init
me           336  0.0  0.0   6208  5040 pts/0    Ss   09:13   0:00  |       \_ -bash
me           459  0.0  0.0   7908  3400 pts/0    R+   09:36   0:00  |           \_ ps -auxf
root         337  0.0  0.0   7528  4896 pts/1    Ss   09:13   0:00  \_ /bin/login -f
me           395  0.0  0.0   6120  4940 pts/1    S+   09:13   0:00      \_ -bash
root          38  0.0  0.0  47728 15328 ?        S<s  09:13   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root          58  0.0  0.0  22084  5872 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root          72  0.0  0.0   4492   156 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 snapfuse /var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap /snap/bare/5 -o ro,nodev,allow_other,suid
root          74  0.0  0.0   4624   172 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 snapfuse /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 -o ro,nodev,allow_other,suid
root          75  0.0  0.0   4784  1720 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 snapfuse /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_607.snap /snap/core22/607 -o ro,nodev,allow_other,suid
root          76  0.1  0.0   4808  1736 ?        Ss   09:13   0:02 snapfuse /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_18933.snap /snap/snapd/18933 -o ro,nodev,allow_other,suid
root          78  0.0  0.0   4768  1768 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 snapfuse /var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-desktop-installer_967.snap /snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/967 -o ro,nodev,allow
systemd+      96  0.0  0.0  25528 12512 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
root         133  0.0  0.0   4304  2680 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P
message+     134  0.0  0.0   8596  4576 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 @dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
root         139  0.0  0.1  30104 19676 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
syslog       140  0.0  0.0 222400 11164 ?        Ssl  09:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
root         141  0.0  0.3 1613668 49524 ?       Ssl  09:13   0:00 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
root         146  0.0  0.0  15320  7224 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root         200  0.0  0.0   4780  3380 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /bin/bash /snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/967/bin/subiquity-server
root         351  0.2  0.4 614084 80424 ?        Sl   09:13   0:03  \_ /snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/967/usr/bin/python3.10 -m subiquity.cmd.server --use-os-prober --storage-version=
root         407  0.1  0.2  43780 37708 ?        S    09:13   0:02      \_ python3 /snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/967/usr/bin/cloud-init status --wait
root         202  0.0  0.1 107208 21372 ?        Ssl  09:13   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
root         206  0.0  0.0   3236  1116 hvc0     Ss+  09:13   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear --keep-baud console 115200,38400,9600 vt220
root         208  0.0  0.0   3192  1060 tty1     Ss+  09:13   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
me           388  0.0  0.0  16936  8836 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
me           389  0.0  0.0 168748  3356 ?        S    09:13   0:00  \_ (sd-pam)
redis        426  0.1  0.1  64252 21788 ?        Ssl  09:15   0:02 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

A lot of snap stuff on the new machine.

### Details

| . | Old Machine | New Machine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Host | Win 10 Pro 19045 x64 | Win 10 Pro 19045 x64 |
| WSL version | 2 | 2 |
| WSL guest distro | Ubuntu 20.04.3 | Ubuntu 22.04.3 |
| redis-server | 5.0.7 | 6.0.16 |

Comment: Your solution will be to install Redis for Windows.  This is a known limitation in WSL that when you close your WSL shell window it will terminate WSL processes after some time, and there does not appear to be a workaround as this is what is inbuilt into the WSL system by Microsoft.